# trigger apex method if user clicks on an app from app launcher

Tags: tracking

I am trying to understand how can I trigger my apex method if any user click on any app from app launcher? I need to get App Details from UserAppInfo object and for that I need to know when user has selected/changed the current App.

Another way I am thinking is put a js script that will check if user clicked url contains "app" then also I can trigger apex method from js. But not sure where to put this js so that on any page load it can check for the url

Comment: Do you mean you need to call some method from a doinit of a LWC/Aura component when an app is loaded?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, try adding a custom LWC/Aura component to the App's home page. That custom component can then invoke your Apex.

Comment: @Christoph Agreed to your point, but that may not get me correct information every time because when user will select the app from app launcher he may not get redirected to that app home page if in that app there are other tabs open for objects. Then the user will be redirected to that specific tab and component from home page will never trigger

Comment: @Akash This is basically the same as your [previous question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/334225/get-user-clicked-link-inside-salesforce) - please [edit] instead of reposting.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot inject arbitrary JavaScript or Apex calls into every Salesforce page from within the Salesforce platform. At best, you can position components within specific customizable pages that perform actions upon load.

You can explore the [Real-Time Event Monitoring](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2020/05/introduction-to-real-time-event-monitoring.html) product, which may cover what you need:

> A common use case of real-time events is an organization that is required to track access to sensitive health data that is stored in Salesforce. Each time a user accesses a page, a Lighting URI Event is created and streamed to its subscribers. The event contains the page identifiers, user information and session details of the page view.

You subscribe to those event streams through the Streaming API or query the data store with Async SOQL. Access to these events requires a paid add-on product.